# Simple Moving Average Backtest: Cumulative Return too high

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, backtesting, moving-average

I apologize if this is way too basic a question, but I'm an absolute beginner to trading and am in the process of learning the fundamentals.

Currently I'm trying to model a (10-day) SMA backtest in Excel, where signals are generated due to crossovers between the closing prices and the 10-day SMA. I calculate the daily and cumulative returns based on closing prices for the asset, and then get the daily returns of the strategy by multiplying the daily asset returns by 1 (if long) or -1 (if short) (this method of getting strategy daily returns has been suggested in a couple of blogs that I'd referred to previously).

Finally I calculate the cumulative returns for the strategy. The problem is that the cumulative returns grow insanely large (I guess up to the order of $10^{15}$). I can't understand what I'm doing wrong - whether the formulae to compute returns are wrong or if the logic itself is incorrect.

I would be grateful if someone could check out the excel sheet (google drive link below) and let me know or at least give me a hint of where I'm making a mistake (or mistakes).

[Link to excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-2nHF8a0j3XZXZNZ2tNMzJaWTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moving average is determined as of the close of a particular day. Then to calculate the P&L you have to multiply today's state (1 or -1) by TOMORROWs return, instead you are using todays! So for example the formula in H13 needs to be E14/E13-1 and not as you incorrectly have it E13/E12-1.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! But the cumulative return for the strategy is still extremely large. I did get a vague idea from your answer that maybe the signals need to be generated a day after the crossover occurs. Once I implemented that, I got acceptable cumulative returns.

Comment: Hi, how high was your cumulative return?

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind cumulative P&L is pure scholar's.  Follow it and you loss everything. Take spreadsheet and simulate reality of every day trade step by step (strongly recommend include fees) and find out difference!
There is a lot of examples, a lot of discussions based on this "unverified?" assumption.
Use your mind and check what it is written on Internet.

Comment: To implement a trading rule rule in real time for a while as you suggest (without using any money) is a good idea (so called "paper trading"), you can learn things that the backtest would perhaps not show.

Comment: You mean to say continuous forward testing? That's definitely a good tip.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago, I've calculated a 29-day SMA backtesting in Excel with consideration that buying and selling is not able at the same close day where the signal is generated.

> **Don't forget the transaction costs!**

When **transaction costs** would be **0%** (...or not included) the performance would look like this: 
[image: Performance without transaction costs]

When **transaction costs** would be **0.45%** the performance would look like this: 
[image]

When **transaction costs** would be **1%**, the strategy would go bankrupt just some years after launching (do you see the blue line at the bottom?): 
[image]